# missing window specification for this function and getting error because of ROW_NUMBER() OVER from dual

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
  insert into att_sch_emp_tmp(
  COMPANYCODE, DIVISIONCODE, CATEGORYICSTABLECODE,
   CATEGORYCODE, CATEGORYTYPE,CODE,
   FACTORYCODE, DEPARTMENTDEPARTMENTCODE, SECTIONSECTIONICSTABLECODE,
   SECTIONSECTIONCODE, MATYPEMACHINETYPEICSTABLECODE, MACHINETYPEMACHINETYPECODE,
   MACHINENOMACHINENOICSTABLECODE, MACHINENOMACHINENOCODE, GRADEICSTABLECODE,
   GRADECODE, CADREICSTABLECODE, CADRECODE,
   DESGDESIGNATIONICSTABLECODE, DESGDESIGNATIONCODE, EMPROLECODE,
   SUBCTGSUBCATEGORYICSTABLECODE, SUBCATEGORYSUBCATEGORYCODE, FROMDATE,
   TODATE, CONFIRMATIONDATE, RESIGNDATE,
   JOININGDATE, CREATIONTIMESTAMP, SERIAL,
   COSTCENTERBADLICODE, HOLIDAYCODE, EFFECTIVEDATE,
   SHIFTROTATIONCODE, WEEKLYOFF, FREQUENCY,
   FREQUENCYDAYS 
  )
  select COMPANYCODE, DIVISIONCODE, CATEGORYICSTABLECODE,
         CATEGORYCODE, CATEGORYTYPE,CODE,
         FACTORYCODE, DEPARTMENTDEPARTMENTCODE, SECTIONSECTIONICSTABLECODE,
         SECTIONSECTIONCODE, MATYPEMACHINETYPEICSTABLECODE, MACHINETYPEMACHINETYPECODE,
         MACHINENOMACHINENOICSTABLECODE, MACHINENOMACHINENOCODE, GRADEICSTABLECODE,
         GRADECODE, CADREICSTABLECODE, CADRECODE,
         DESGDESIGNATIONICSTABLECODE, DESGDESIGNATIONCODE, EMPROLECODE,
         SUBCTGSUBCATEGORYICSTABLECODE, SUBCATEGORYSUBCATEGORYCODE, FROMDATE,
         TODATE, CONFIRMATIONDATE, RESIGNDATE,
         JOININGDATE, p_creationtimestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER from dual(),
         ' ', ' ', sysdate,
         ' ', 0, 0,
         0
  from  employee
```

Comment: while compiling i am getting an error
ROW_NUMBER() OVER from dual() at this line
missing window specification for this function

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax without partitioning :

```
SELECT ......
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) 
FROM ...
```

If you want it partitioned by a department or W/E then :

```
SELECT ......
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YourColumn ORDER BY TheOrderColumn) 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement with dual is incorrect. Dual is a table you need to specify how should row_number be calculated. You probably need:

```
select COMPANYCODE, DIVISIONCODE, CATEGORYICSTABLECODE,
         CATEGORYCODE, CATEGORYTYPE,CODE,
         FACTORYCODE, DEPARTMENTDEPARTMENTCODE, SECTIONSECTIONICSTABLECODE,
         SECTIONSECTIONCODE, MATYPEMACHINETYPEICSTABLECODE, MACHINETYPEMACHINETYPECODE,
         MACHINENOMACHINENOICSTABLECODE, MACHINENOMACHINENOCODE, GRADEICSTABLECODE,
         GRADECODE, CADREICSTABLECODE, CADRECODE,
         DESGDESIGNATIONICSTABLECODE, DESGDESIGNATIONCODE, EMPROLECODE,
         SUBCTGSUBCATEGORYICSTABLECODE, SUBCATEGORYSUBCATEGORYCODE, FROMDATE,
         TODATE, CONFIRMATIONDATE, RESIGNDATE,
         JOININGDATE, p_creationtimestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by 1),
         ' ', ' ', sysdate,
         ' ', 0, 0,
         0
  from  employee;
```

And if you just want row number without any specified partition or order you can replace `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by 1)` with `rownum`. Or if you want some specified order replace `1` by name of column that indicates order.

Also you need to be aware that when you execute insert second time your `SERIAL` will start again from `1`. If you need there unique numbers please do

`create sequence serial_seq start with 1 increment by 1;`

and use:

```
select COMPANYCODE, DIVISIONCODE, CATEGORYICSTABLECODE,
         CATEGORYCODE, CATEGORYTYPE,CODE,
         FACTORYCODE, DEPARTMENTDEPARTMENTCODE, SECTIONSECTIONICSTABLECODE,
         SECTIONSECTIONCODE, MATYPEMACHINETYPEICSTABLECODE, MACHINETYPEMACHINETYPECODE,
         MACHINENOMACHINENOICSTABLECODE, MACHINENOMACHINENOCODE, GRADEICSTABLECODE,
         GRADECODE, CADREICSTABLECODE, CADRECODE,
         DESGDESIGNATIONICSTABLECODE, DESGDESIGNATIONCODE, EMPROLECODE,
         SUBCTGSUBCATEGORYICSTABLECODE, SUBCATEGORYSUBCATEGORYCODE, FROMDATE,
         TODATE, CONFIRMATIONDATE, RESIGNDATE,
         JOININGDATE, p_creationtimestamp, serial_seq.nextval,
         ' ', ' ', sysdate,
         ' ', 0, 0,
         0
  from  employee;
```